# UTF8 filename failing in IIS

Tags: utf-8, windows-xp, iis-5

I have an  element in a web page containing a UTF-8 encoded filename URL

<A HREF='http://server/site/%E8%A8%82%E8%B2%A8%E6%97%A5%E7%B5%90%E5%A4%B1%E6%95%97.txt'>訂貨日結失敗.txt</A>

This returns a 404 page from IIS. The file exists in the correct location on the server.

When I monitor what IIS is looking for using ProcMon, I can see it attempting to find a file that looks like the raw bytes from the UTF-8 string rather than the UTF-16 (?) string.

È¨‚È²¨Æ—¥ÇµÅ¤±Æ•—.TXT

I'd have thought IIS would have done the UTF-8 to UTF-16 conversion to look for the filename on the server.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong.

Ta,
J

Comment: What version of IIS? What OS version?

Comment: Testing on XP with IIS5 at the moment.

Comment: Looks like I need to use IIS 6 as a minimum. I've just tested it and it seems to work OK. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301710.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I need to use IIS 6 as a minimum. I've just tested it and it seems to work OK. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301710.aspx